# Is Gesture typing a part of AOSP LatinIME?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-source, ime, swipe-gesture

I can build the AOSP Stock keyboard (LatinIME) from source available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/) but gesture typing does not seem to work. [Some](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=34605586) [sources](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/39225-compiling-jellybean-latinimeapk/#entry1105515) tell me that gesture typing is not a part of AOSP as it is proprietary to Google. Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is true. The default LatinIME does not even have a modern dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/general/guide-how-to-enable-googles-gesture-t2012628/post34605586

in the first source link you shared, it actually mentioned how to make it works.

> BUT! There is a way! You can drop in replace the lib from "LatinImeGoogle.apk" into your system/lib and you will have your gesture decoder!

Comment: Thank you for your response. And yes I know that I can have gesture typing work by copying the lib from Google's APK but still it is not open source and I cannot include it to my fork of LatinIME.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is true that swipe/gesture typing is not included in the AOSP app. If you want, you can, however, [extract the library used for this from the GApps](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/187686/158241) and manually install it.